# freeswitch.Dbh cause freeswitch auto shudtown

Tags: mysql, lua, odbc, shutdown, freeswitch

When I freeswitch test lua odbc mysql in my docker, when exec to freeswitch.Dbh("db","user","password"), the freeswitch auto shutdown.
Anybody met this issue, can give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

already fixed this issue,because my docker freeswitch ./confiure not enable-core-odbc-dsn,not support odbc mysql,i use postgres,this issue fixed.